# Checkout files in SVN

Tags: svn

I use this commands to checkout a file in my computer
`svn --depth empty checkout svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/ d:\currecnt\class
cd d:\currecnt\class\
svn update MBackingBean.java`

that command work correctly and checkout **MBackingBean.java** from repository to my location but when i execute for second time for other file
`svn --depth empty checkout svn://mcdssrv/repos/currecnt/class/ d:\currecnt\class
cd d:\currecnt\class\
svn update OtherFile.java`   previous file **MBackingBean.java** deleted. So, how can i fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

With `--depth empty`, you instruct `svn checkout` command to check out its target folder *only*. Quoting the [**doc**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.depth):

> **--depth ARG**
>
> Instructs Subversion to limit the scope of an operation to a particular tree depth. 
>   `ARG` is one of...
>
> - `empty` (only the target itself),
> - `files` (the target and any immediate file children thereof)
> - `immediates` (the target and any immediate children thereof), or
> - `infinity` (the target and all of its descendants—full recursion).

So what you have actually checked out after that command executed is just an empty folder.
No wonder that only the specific file checked out then with `svn update` will appear there.

Answer (score 0):

You used two commands for each file. The first command gives you an empty directory. The second command gives you a file within that directory.

Since after the first two commands you already have a directory, you don't need to create it again. Just execute the "update" command and omit the "checkout" command for the second file.